# Conexão do SQLServer Localhost no DBeaver? Erro de Conexão?

Tags: sql, dbeaver

Quero conectar o Localhost do SQLServer no Gerenciador DBeaver. Porém ao tentar o mesmo dá o erro:

```
The TCP/IP connection to the host mssql., port 1433 has failed. Error: "Este host não é conhecido (mssql.). Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei com `Localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, `mssql.`, sempre dá o esmo erro.

Tenho o Localhost conectado no Management Studio, funcionando normalmente.

Com a mesma conexão

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho que fazer alguma coisa de diferente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entendi aqui,

tenho que mudar uma configuração:

Entra em

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager15.msc

Habilitar o terceiro serviço
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E nessa tela vai dando restart nos serviços

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora só conectar.